# R package build from source control

Tags: r, package

I'm creating R package and every file related to the package needs to be locked in source control. This includes DESCRIPTION file, which is required for R packages.
If this file is checked out, package is built without problems. If it is locked I get permission error. I think it is because build is trying to add date and time information to it. Is there any solution for this.

thank you.

[update 1]
by "locked" I mean checked-in. I'm not building for CRAN, it is a set of R tools to be by a couple of teams inside the company

[update 2]

Error on console:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
Warning in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'my_pkg/DESCRIPTION': Permission denied
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open the connection
Execution halted

Comment: I’m not sure what “locked” refers to in version control context. SourceSafe and SVN had this concept, I think, but none of the modern systems do as far as I know. And at any rate that wouldn’t lead to the effect you’re observing. What exactly do you mean? How exactly are you building the package?

Comment: You have not shown us the console transcript, but the other thing that CRAN checks for is whether the version number has been incremented.

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve it, would be to check-in DESCRIPTION.template file into source control, then during build make a local copy called DESCRIPTION